# Pandas: pad series on top or bottom

Tags: pandas, series

This turned out to be non-trivial for me so I wanted to check if others have a simple solution for this:

Suppose I have an arbitrary number (say 3) of `pd.Series`: which look like:

```
first = pd.Series(range(5))
second = pd.Series(range(7))
third = pd.Series(range(6))
```

I'd like to make them all of the same length (7 -- which is the largest length) and pad the shorter ones with `np.nan`s either at the top (optionally at the bottom) so that first looks like:

```
nan
nan
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) to give each Series a new index. If the new index contains labels which are not in the original series' index, then a `NaN` value is filled in (unless a different `fill_value` is specified):

```
In [15]: first.reindex(range(7))
Out[15]: 
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    NaN
6    NaN
dtype: float64
```

You can control the placement of the NaNs by your choice of reindexing labels:

```
In [19]: first.reindex(range(-2,5))
Out[19]: 
-2    NaN
-1    NaN
 0    0.0
 1    1.0
 2    2.0
 3    3.0
 4    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Note that the inclusion of `NaN`s forces the dtype of `first` to be promoted from an integer dtype to a floating-point dtype since `NaN`s are floats (and hence Series of integer dtype can not contain `NaN`s).

Comment: Thanks. I had a hunch but was not able to fix it. I need to wait for a while before accepting the answer.